# If given a table of samples from a multivariate distribution, can you get multivariate marginals by just extracting the columns you are interested in?

Tags: sampling, marginal-distribution, probabilistic-programming

If we let $p(x)$ be the joint probability density where of r.v. $x$ where $x \in \mathbb{R}^{10}$

I am interested in looking at the joint marginal $p_{x_3, x_4, x_5}(x_3, x_4, x_5)$  I know that mathematically this is equal to $\int_{x_0,...,x_2,x_6,...} p(x)  dx_0...dx_2,dx_6,...$

But what is the best way to do this empirically? (i.e. with samples)

Let's say I have a dataset, $\hat{p}$, with size=(1,000 rows, 10 columns) where the rows are samples and the columns are $x_1, x_2,...$ . Would $p_{x_3, x_4, x_5}(x_3, x_4, x_5) \approx \hat{p}$[: , 3,4,5] (the 3, 4, and 5th columns of the empirical dataset $\hat{p}$)?

I believe this is correct, and I am just overthinking it, but I just wanted to make sure! Thank you!

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "looking at"?  For instance, if that involves parametric estimation then the answers may be quite different than if it literally just means "examining" or "visualizing."

Comment: Sorry, I should've been more specific. I do not mean parametrizing the density. Instead, I meant if given the dataset, a histogram of the 4th column would be (in an empirical sense) the marginal distribution $p_{x_4}(x_4)$ right? So would this generalize to if you took the 4th, 5th, and 6th column, would that be (in an empirical sense) the multivariate marginal  $p_{x_4, x_5, x_6} (x_4, x_5, x_6)$?

Comment: That's the definition of "marginal."

Comment: Okay phew. I know this is very elementary and I was definitely overthinking it. I was looking for someone to confirm it for me. Thank you!